# Primefaces table, sort column by element in iteration

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I need to sort a column by a element which would be from to iterate a list as follows

```
<p:column sortBy="WHATEVER" style="width:11%;" >
  <f:facet name="header">#{msg['tbl_hdr_trnsldr.manage_po']}</f:facet>
  <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{po.poBuList}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.poRole eq 'Transloader'?item.bu.ref:''}" />
  </ui:repeat>
</p:column>
```

In ui:repeat will be a (and just one) item which its ref will be Transloader, however in the list would be more type of items.

I've been looking for it but I've found nothing similar

Any suggestion??

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: why don't you do the 'iteration' in a backingbean? Then the column has a specific value and you can easily sort

Comment: Thank you Kukeltje. I'll must create a new class to store the data and populate it with the data that come from database. Thanks for suggestion